# Selection/range/caret position bugging out after manipulating the DOM

Tags: javascript, html, dom, contenteditable

I have a small project I'm working on where there's a contenteditable div that you can edit. When you're at the front of the line and you press backspace, I wanted it so that the current line gets added to the one above, the caret gets moved to the correct position, and clears out the number to the left as well. The same happens when you press enter but I removed that from the example since it's unnecessary. I managed to do that with manipulating the nodes but what I noticed is that after pressing backspace and joining the two sections, pressing backspace again does nothing but if I press any other letter/number, it starts working again. Is there a way to fix this so that you can press backspace again and if possible just continuously hold backspace and it behaves as you'd expect it to.

I've even tried moving this section of the code

```
        const selection = window.getSelection();
        const node = selection.anchorNode;
        const range = selection.getRangeAt(0);
        const position = range.startOffset;
        const hasSelection = selection.toString().length > 0;
        const currentNode = node.parentElement;
```

Into it's own "initialize" function and calling that after the joining happens, but that didn't end up working either.

Any help is appreciated!

Here's the working example: https://codepen.io/a-single-pringle/pen/mdzjbWR